# Email Placeholders in Array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on Email Module. In Email Template, User can Drag the Placeholders.

The placeholders are like this :- [USERNAME], [ADDRESS].

So, e.g of Dynamic Email Template is like this :-

```
Hi [USERNAME],

Welcome to our site 

[ADDRESS]
.....
```

I want to collect all the Placeholders in a Array or List of Strings in the Controller.

How to extract placeholders?

Comment: Help clarify a few things: can *anything* be a placeholder that matches this pattern, or is there a fixed finite set of placeholders? What are you trying to do with the contents of these placeholders? I.e. once you have an array of strings-- what do you expect to do with it? Do you literally just want to get an array back that is basically `["[USERNAME]", "[ADDRESS]"]`?

Comment: Further I need to replace the PLACEHOLDERS with the actual data..!

Comment: Yes...anything which matches this pattern will be a Placeholder..!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Placeholder>\[[A-Z]+\])");
```